# Is there a way to use resources created by ec2 user data in my cloudformation stack for another resource in the stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

im working on a template in which i deploy an ec2 instance, in the instances user data, the instance pulls a script from a git repo and uses that script create an AMI. I would like to refer to that newly created ami’s ID in another resource in the same cloudformation stack using the either by using !ref or some other way.

so far I have placed this line below in the user data to get the name of the ami

```
export AMIID=$(aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=ami-name" | jq -r ".Images[].ImageId")
```

and this line to create an entry to put the AMI ID in the parameter store

```
aws ssm put-parameter --name aminame --type String --value "$AMIID"
```

In the cloudformation stack I have a parameter here

```
AMI:
    Type : 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: aminame
```

and in the resource block I have this the reference to the ami that looks something like this

```
EC2Instance:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
      CreationPolicy:
        ResourceSignal:
          Timeout: PT120M
      Properties:
          ImageId: !Ref AMI
      UserData:
            Fn::Base64: |
            #!/bin/bash
```

So far when I run this I get an error stating that the parameter cannot be found.. which makes sense, however is there any other way to do something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can do that using lambda:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html

Comment: "But it is a lot of work." is irrelevant if this is the only way to achieve what OP requires.